# Status code 404 when calling spring-boot API, but not for postman or browser

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, httpurlconnection

I want to make an API call to a local REST server built with Spring-Boot which is interacting with mongodb. I already checked some posts which I found to this topic, but my problem seems to be a little bit different.

Here are some code snippets which are relevant:

```
protected static CoreEntity[] sendGET(CoreEntity[] resultList, String path) throws IOException {
    path = String.join("%20", path.split(" "));
    return handleResponse(resultList, getConnection(path, "Get"));
}

private static HttpURLConnection getConnection(String path, String requestMethod) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(REQUEST_URL + path);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(50000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(50000);
    connection.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
    initializeGSON();
    return connection;
}

private static CoreEntity[] handleResponse(CoreEntity[] resultList, HttpURLConnection connection) {
    try {
        final int status = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // Success
            try (InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()); BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { response.append(inputLine); }
                reader.close();
                in.close();
                JSONArray jsonArray = getJSONAsArray(response.toString());
                resultList = (CoreEntity[]) Array.newInstance(resultList.getClass().getComponentType(), jsonArray.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    resultList[i] = (CoreEntity) GSON.fromJson(jsonArray.get(i).toString(), resultList.getClass().getComponentType());
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nRequest failed with error code: " + status);
        }
        connection.disconnect();
        return resultList;
    } catch (ConnectException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The response for http://www.google.com or any other homepage is successful with status code 200. But as soon as I call my API I get an error with status code 404. Strange is that everything works when I am using Postman or the browser. So when I do a get request via postman to the following method (http://localhost:8080/pets/3), I can see the print out and get the data from mongodb, but not for the code above. For the code above nothing happens on server side, no print out, no exception, nothing.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<T> getById(@PathVariable final long id) {
    System.out.println("TEST ===> " + id);
    T entity = getService().getById(id);
    return entity == null ? ResponseEntity.notFound().build() : ResponseEntity.ok(entity);
}
```

It seems like my application is not able to find the API, but I already verified that the URL is correct which is why I don’t understand the error code 404.

I also read about package visibility, but my structure looks like the following which is why I don't think that this is the reason.

[Package Structure (Don't be confused from name Aerospike)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrjpN.png)

I've spend way too much time for this now, and I am really desperate for help and hope you can help me or at least point me in the right direction.

**Edit**

Here is the entire RestController:

```
@Controller
public abstract class CoreController<S extends CoreService<T>, T extends CoreEntity> {

    public static final String SERVER = "http://localhost", PORT = ":8080",
        CORE_API = SERVER + PORT + "/"; // controller/v2/
    public static final String ID = "id";
    private String api;

    public CoreController() { }
    public CoreController(final String api) { this.api = CORE_API + api; }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{" + ID + "}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<T> getById(@PathVariable final long id) {
        System.out.println("TEST ===> " + id);
        T entity = getService().getById(id);
        return entity == null ? ResponseEntity.notFound().build() : ResponseEntity.ok(entity);
    }

    public abstract S getService();
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "pets/")
public class PetController extends CoreController<PetService, Pet> {

    @Autowired
    protected PetService service;
    public static final String API = "pets";

    public PetController() { super(API); }

    public PetService getService() { return service; }
}
```

Here the evidence that the spring-boot is listening on 8080 and also postman works with port 8080.

[Server print out on start up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVngF.png)

Comment: Can you show the entire RestController class?
You running to app simultaneously on your local PC, you sure port 8080 is the one that your spring boot is configured to?

Comment: @asfmlr I added the RestController class and picture of server print out on startup. Please checkout **Edit**

Comment: You are aware that Spring's RestTemplate will do almost everything inside your client code automatically for you?

Comment: @chrylis Okay, but nevertheless calling the API via `HttpURLConnection` should work too?

Comment: @chrylis I implemented RestTemplate as described [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/). But no change. The response is `HTTP GET http://localhost:8080/pets/1` `Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]` `Response 404 NOT_FOUND`

Comment: @Nadine have you found any solution yet? I am also facing same issue. If yes, please share.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing the slash ("/") in the start and you have duplicate in the end of the exposed value so it's looking for pets//{id} in the controller change to value = { "/pets"}
Anyway, when starting the service syou should see in the logs the exposed uri's

Comment: The exposed uri seems to be okay `Mapped "{[/pets/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<T> com.betai.aerospike.controller.core.CoreController.getById(long)` and wouldn't postman fail too, if the exposed uri would be incorrect?

Comment: what is the "path" input for sendGET method?

Comment: The "path" input is `pets/1` and combined with `REQUEST_URL` in `getConnection` I get `http://localhost:8080/pets/1`

Comment: ok, sorry for the late response, so in postman it is working for the same the id?
I see you returning no_found also in the code, could it be it?
in postman you see in the log "TEST ===>" and locally not?

Comment: Yes, postman is working for the same id. The application does not even reach no_found and also not the log "TEST ===>" when I run it locally, but in postman I can see the log.

Comment: hi, does it solve?
took me time to understand but I think you should change the request method to "GET" and not "Get" 
or remove it as it is the default